# Error while changing QObject stylesheet in a Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

## Context

I want to build QObject animations in python. For example, I tried animating the background of a QLineEdit object in order to make a "red flash" when a something wrong is entered. The function is working, the thread starts and I see the animation, but when the thread ends, the app collapses without error trace-back. I only get

```
exit code -1073740940
```

Which I didn't find on the internet.

## Minimal Working Example

Here's a mwe that I made in order for you to reproduce this error with only one file. You will notice that the important part of the code is inside LoginDialog class.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys


class Ui_LoginUi(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_LoginUi):
        Ui_LoginUi.setObjectName("LoginUi")
        Ui_LoginUi.resize(293, 105)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.le_test = QLineEdit(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.le_test)


class LoginDialog(QDialog, Ui_LoginUi):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.le_test.textChanged.connect(self.redFlashThreader)

    def redFlashThreader(self):
        self.redFlashTread1 = Thread(target=self.lineEdit_redFlash, args=[self.le_test])
        self.redFlashTread1.start()

    def lineEdit_redFlash(self, *args):
        inital_r = 255
        initial_g = 127
        initial_b = 127

        for i in range(64):
            initial_g += 2
            initial_b += 2
            time.sleep(0.005)
            args[0].setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,{},{})".format(initial_g, initial_b))

        args[0].setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = LoginDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## Results

If you click multiple times, the app will freeze and crash. I would like to understand why, but without trace-back, I find that quite hard. Sometimes, it happens after the first click. I thought it would be a thread conflict problem, but since it happens with only the first thread running, I'm not so sure. Anyone could point me in the right direction or explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question allows to analyze the following aspects:

### 1) You should not update directly any GUI element from another thread

The painting of the GUI is done in the main thread so the GUI do not allow in any case to modify any property that involves painting from another thread, so if the developer does it there is no guarantee that works as in this case what's wrong. For more information read [GUI Thread and Worker Thread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).

In the case of Qt if you want to update some GUI element from another thread what you should do is send by some means (signals, QEvent, QMetaObject::invokeMethod(), etc) the information to the main thread, and in the main thread do the update.

So considering the above, a possible solution using signals is the following:

```py
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_LoginUi(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_LoginUi):
        Ui_LoginUi.setObjectName("LoginUi")
        Ui_LoginUi.resize(293, 105)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.le_test = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_LoginUi)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_test)


class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LoginUi):
    colorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.le_test.textChanged.connect(self.redFlashThreader)
        self.colorChanged.connect(self.on_color_change)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def redFlashThreader(self):
        self.redFlashTread1 = Thread(
            target=self.lineEdit_redFlash, args=[self.le_test]
        )
        self.redFlashTread1.start()

    def lineEdit_redFlash(self, *args):
        inital_r = 255
        initial_g = 127
        initial_b = 127

        for i in range(64):
            initial_g += 2
            initial_b += 2
            time.sleep(0.005)
            self.colorChanged.emit(QtGui.QColor(255, initial_g, initial_b))
        self.colorChanged.emit(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_color_change(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: %s}" % (color.name(),))

        """ or
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "QLineEdit{ background-color: rgb(%d, %d, %d)}"
            % (color.red(), color.green(), color.blue())
        )"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = LoginDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### 2) It is not necessary to use threads to make animation in Qt, instead you should use QVariantAnimation, QPropertyAnimation, etc.

In a GUI you should avoid using threading since it can bring more problems than benefits (for example saturate the signal queue), so use it as a last resort. In this case you can use [`QVariantAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html) or [`QPropertyAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html):

#### 2.1) QVariantAnimation

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_LoginUi(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_LoginUi):
        Ui_LoginUi.setObjectName("LoginUi")
        Ui_LoginUi.resize(293, 105)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.le_test = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Ui_LoginUi)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_test)


class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LoginUi):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.le_test.textChanged.connect(self.start_animation)

        self.m_animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            startValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 127, 127),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255),
            duration=1000,
            valueChanged=self.on_color_change,
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_animation(self):
        if self.m_animation.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self.m_animation.stop()
        self.m_animation.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtGui.QColor)
    def on_color_change(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background-color: %s}" % (color.name(),))

        """ or
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "QLineEdit{ background-color: rgb(%d, %d, %d)}"
            % (color.red(), color.green(), color.blue())
        )"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = LoginDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### 2.2) QPropertyAnimation

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    backgroundColorChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtGui.QColor)

    def backgroundColor(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_background_color"):
            self._background_color = QtGui.QColor()
            self.setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        return self._background_color

    def setBackgroundColor(self, color):
        if self._background_color != color:
            self._background_color = color
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color: {}".format(color.name()))
            self.backgroundColorChanged.emit(color)

    backgroundColor = QtCore.pyqtProperty(
        QtGui.QColor,
        fget=backgroundColor,
        fset=setBackgroundColor,
        notify=backgroundColorChanged,
    )


class Ui_LoginUi(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_LoginUi):
        Ui_LoginUi.setObjectName("LoginUi")
        Ui_LoginUi.resize(293, 105)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.le_test = LineEdit(Ui_LoginUi)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_test)


class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_LoginUi):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.le_test.textChanged.connect(self.start_animation)

        self.m_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self.le_test,
            b'backgroundColor',
            self,
            startValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 127, 127),
            endValue=QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255),
            duration=1000,
        )

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def start_animation(self):
        if self.m_animation.state() == QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self.m_animation.stop()
        self.m_animation.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = LoginDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: why do you add `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` in the 1st solution using signals? It seems to work even without this decorator

Comment: @nathancy It works without the decorator but it placed it as good practice since in this case there are no problems but other cases could. It also has other important advantages: it reduces the memory consumed in the connection and makes the invocation faster. Please, read  https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator

Comment: @nathancy Actually if there is a negative aspect if you abuse its use. Do you think that implementing signals and slots do not have a cost? It has a cost on the C++ side, to implement those functionalities the MOC is used that leads to a greater use of memory and that is easy to understand, while more things are implemented more memory is consumed besides the connection creates a LUT. So Qt signals uses the signals and slots when necessary.

Comment: @nathancy On the other hand by design you should only use things when necessary, when to implement a slot? then when you assume that function can be invoked with the eventloop, or when you want it to be reflected in Qt metaobject, when you want to use it in QML, etc. In conclusion use it when necessary and it will bring you beneficial, if you abuse you could have problems. So from the side of Qt gives you freedom and the same agrees with the principle of python that "We are consenting adults" so it is our responsibility to use or not.

Comment: @nathancy If you check the Qt classes you will notice that only some methods are slots: Qt wants to have a light code. That is the same principle because Qt does not implement the exceptions. Or have you not had curiosities because in PyQt there is no need to use try-except?

Comment: Thank you for the incredible explanation. Yes, I've always wondered why there was no need to use try/except. I guess it makes sense now

Comment: Thank you @ eyllanesc, really well explained. Though, I wondered wouldn't it be more simple and clean to create a custom QLineEdit class, as you suggested, but incorporate all the mechanic inside the class, which remove the necessity to use lots of signals and slots. I think that this way you cand build widgets with multiple animations without overcoding. exemple that works, just add the startValue, endValue and duration attributes: I would like to understand why this wouldn't be a good option in your opinion.

Comment: `class CustomLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    @property
    def bgColor(self):
        return self._backgroundColor
    @bgColor.setter
    def bgColor(self, color):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: {}".format(color.name()))
    def __init__(self, qtObject):
        super(CustomLineEdit, self).__init__(qtObject)
    def redFlash(self):
        self.anim_redFlash = QVariantAnimation()
        self.anim_redFlash.valueChanged.connect(self.changeBackground)
        self.anim_redFlash.start()
    def changeBackground(self, color):
        self.bgColor = color`

Comment: @M-A.Vigneault I understand your point, but your code is the same as my example of QVariantAnimation since the main part remains, it is great that you have understood and modified it for your tastes. The objective of the second part of my answer is to point out that there are better alternatives and to show you an example of how you could implement it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To achieve the 'red flash' when something wrong is entered, you can use [`QTimer.singleShot()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QTimer.singleShot). Essentially when text is changed in the field, and it triggers your wrong text, you can change the background to the error color. Then after a certain amount of time, say 2 seconds later, you can reset the field color.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer 
import time
import sys

class Ui_LoginUi(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui_LoginUi):
        Ui_LoginUi.setObjectName("LoginUi")
        Ui_LoginUi.resize(293, 105)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.le_test = QLineEdit(Ui_LoginUi)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.le_test)

class LoginDialog(QDialog, Ui_LoginUi):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.invalid_color = 'background-color: #c91d2e'
        self.valid_color = 'background-color: #FFF'
        self.le_test.textChanged.connect(self.redFlashHandler)

    def redFlashHandler(self):
        if self.le_test.text() == 'test':
            self.le_test.setStyleSheet(self.invalid_color)

            # After 2000 ms, reset field color
            QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.resetFieldColor)

    def resetFieldColor(self):
        self.le_test.setStyleSheet(self.valid_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = LoginDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That is a work around. But it doesn't really explains the threading problem.